# Add notes to latex beamer

Tags: beamer, notes

I need to add notes for presentation like we add Microsoft PowerPoint 'click to add notes'.  Is there some way to do it using latex beamer?

Comment: Please examine chapter 19 of the `beamer` user's guide. You can obtain it by entering `texdoc beamer` in yout terminal. Otherwise you can go here: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf

Comment: @Henri Menke, that link is broken.

Comment: @PaulWintz Yes, that is unfortunate. The texdoc.net service started out very promising but was abandoned for some time and when it was picked up by other developers, the URL format was changed, so all links from before that time are broken. It's better to link to the CTAN mirror directly: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can write everything you want between frame environment into a `note` command. With the option `[itemize]` everything you write into the note will look like an itemize list.

```
%\documentclass[notes]{beamer}       % print frame + notes
\documentclass[notes=only]{beamer}   % only notes
%\documentclass{beamer}              % only frames

\title[Your Short Title]{Your Presentation}
\author{You}
\institute{Where You're From}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduction}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Your introduction goes here!
  \item Use \texttt{itemize} to organize your main points.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\note{Everything you want}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Development}

    Lot of interesting things

\end{frame}

\note[itemize]{
\item point 1
\item point 2
}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Development}

    Lot of interesting things

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

See here on write latex : https://www.writelatex.com/181070qqjrgq

Comment: Does the note go before the frame or after the frame?

Comment: It looks like the note command is associated with the previous slide.  So, they need to come *after* the frame command.

Comment: how does "note" work. I do not see notes in generated pdf from the link given in the answer.

Comment: If you specify the beamer documentclass, with the notes option as in the example, it should work.

Comment: How does the itemize option work ?

Comment: But what about overlays? How can you assign a note to a specific one?